# how to get started with angular animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't get an `ng-view` animation to run at all. The application works and changes views, but the view never changes color.

It seems the `.ng-enter` class is never added to the element. I was under the impression that including `ngAnimate` was all that was needed. Are there more steps?

packages

```
angular 1.3.14
angular-route 1.3.14
angular-animate 1.3.14
```

js

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate',
])
```

scss

```
.view {
  min-height: 600px;

  &.ng-enter {
    background: red;
  }

  &.ng-leave {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

html

```
<section ng-view class="view"></section>
```

Comment: i think this's a good reference http://goo.gl/6atsMc

Comment: @dyaa do I need to define keyframe animations to see it at all?